# vb.net IsFirstRun errors when running application

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in vb.net

```
If My.Application.Deployment.IsFirstRun Then

End If
```

but when i run the program it shows an error saying:

```
application identity is not set
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to check that the application was actually deployed using ClickOnce before using the `Deployment` property.

```
If My.Application.IsNetworkDeployed Then
    If My.Application.Deployment.IsFirstRun Then
        '...
    End If
End If
```

Comment: @user2710234 If `IsNetworkDeployed` is true then the application was deployed using ClickOnce, and the `My.Application.Deployment` object will work.  If you are not using ClickOnce, `My.Application.Deployment.IsFirstRun` is not going to work for you.